# Points for queen in carrom board

Tags: carrom

Whether points for queen in carrom board becomes invalid after reaching 22? Suppose if a player reaches 22 at the end of a round will he get points for the queen

Answer (score 1):

There are some slight variations in the points for pocketing the queen between the different Carrom federations, but most follow the laws set out by the International Carrom Federation, which read as follows:

> HOW TO SCORE
> 52)
>
> - a) The player who completes pocketing all his C/m first wins the board.
> - b) The value/points are as follows:
>
>   - i) Queen : 3 points up to and including 21 points.
>   - ii) C/m : 1 point each.

So once a player has 22 points the Queen becomes worth nothing.